# Define deserialization type with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using Google Gson to de/serialize my app database to/from JSON. The app uses Room database with a custom class which has more than 20 fields, so for semplicity let's consider an example one. I recently changed the type of a field from String to JSON; Room managed the migration fine - just by creating a converter class and adding a void version migration - but I'm not sure how to correclty handle Gson.

Here is the object class, respectively the old and the new one:

Old exClass.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "example_class")
public class exClass {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "json")
    public String json;
}
```

New exClass.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "example_class")
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public class exClass {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "json")
    public JSONObject json;
}
```

Now when trying to restore old database backups (created with the old version of the class) Gson throws an exception, because it's expecting a JSON object for the field "json" but finds a String.

Is there a way to override the type Gson expects without having to create a custom `JsonSerializer<exClass>`?

Note that the JSONObject is still fine as far as Room is concerned: the converter converts "json" to a String before inserting it into the database and viceversa, so it's only a matter of having Gson correcly parse the "json" field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add `Converters`?

Comment: Are you sure the json string is 100% ok?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman what should I add a Converter to?

Comment: Yes @UrielFrankel it's